# Database Form Builder For MS

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-ce, formbuilder

Like the form builder of oracle databases,
Is there a MS form builder !?
As it will get me an output of a .net form that i can show/edit/delete/update data !!
Manipulating data is not one of my project aims, so i want this to be generated instead of writing a form with bindings, grids, linq, datasets, adapters .. etc
So. Is there a MS form builder for SQL Server or SQL compact edition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in Form Builder solution for SQL Server.

However, you can make custom Form application using Visual Studio with very little effort.

Example here: [BindingSource and BindingNavigator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/BindSourceBindingNavCS.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply , although you gave a good example but it's still show one by one row , I want to show all table in a grid , another table in another grid grids have same tables relations , I can do this all but can I generate them dynamically from database ?

Comment: @Ahmed Adel you just need to add DataGridView to the form.